# How to supply existing variable to mutate through reference?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang, forcats

Here is my data:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
         ~A,  ~B,
        "C", "G",
        "D", "H",
        "E", "I",
        "F", "J")

df$A <- as.factor(df$A)

var <- "A"
```

And, I want to relevel A from C to E using, maybe rlang, something like this, but it's not working!

```
var <- syms(var)
df <- df %>% mutate(!!!var = fct_relevel(!!!var, "E"))
```

My desired output is:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(A = fct_relevel(A, "E"))
levels(df$A)
```

But instead of supplying A manually, I want to programmatically supply these, something in line rlang syms using var character vector.

How should I do that?

Comment: `mutate_at` is a simpler solution here

Comment: ok, that's helpful!

Comment: Because the variable is passed to the first parameter, you don't even have to use `funs` or an anonymous function: `var <- 'A'; df %>% mutate_at(var, fct_relevel, 'E')`

Comment: I agree! I just needed to use var as I have to parametrize that in my code.

Comment: You can pass in `var` if you leave it as a string; see the edit above. You use an expression too if you unquote it: `var <- sym('A'); df %>% mutate_at(vars(!!var), fct_relevel, 'E')`, but that's more complicated

Comment: So, I believe, I can do that in one step. df %>% mutate_at(vars(!!sym(var)), fct_relevel, 'E'). This is amazing!

Comment: There's no point in using `sym` in `mutate_at`; just use the string variable bare like the first version: `mutate_at(var, ...)`

Comment: Oh, now I get it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @alistaire's comment but for what it's worth, the correct `rlang` syntax would be:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(!!var := fct_relevel(!!rlang::sym(var), "E"))
levels(df$A);
#[1] "E" "C" "D" "F"
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
         ~A,  ~B,
        "C", "G",
        "D", "H",
        "E", "I",
        "F", "J")

df$A <- as.factor(df$A)

var <- "A"
```

Comment: Yes, I wanted this solution! Thanks! Where can I read more about these !!var and := stuff?

Comment: You're very welcome @Geet. Have a look at the [Quasiquotation chapter](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html) from Hadley's "Advanced R".

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I will look into it.